# masonry not appending to the end of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to append new information to the end of the container instead of loading it to the end it loads it on top of the other info.

I load my data through ajax call, if then have a button. On click of this button it should append data to the end, but it appears in the top left.

```
var makeArticleTemplate = function(newData){
  var string ='';

  /// makes article tile
  for (var i = 0; i < newData.data.length;  i++) {
    var d = newData.data[i];

      string +=  '    <article class="'+d.type+'">',
      string +=  '    <div class="img-wrap">',
      string +=  '    <div class="grad"></div>',
      string +=  '    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/cats/" alt="" />',
      string +=  '    </div>',
      string +=  '    <div class="content-wrap">',
      string +=  '    <div class="publish-date">',
      string +=  '    <p>october</p>',
      string +=  '    <p>2015</p>',
      string +=  '    </div>',
      string +=  '    <div class="content-title">',
      string +=  '    <h3>'+d.title+'<h3>',
      string +=  '    </div>',
      string +=  '    <div class="summary">',
      string +=  '    <p>'+d.subtitle+'</p>',
      string +=  '    </div>',
      string +=  '    <div class="event-date">',
      string +=  '    <div class="event-date-month">',
      string +=  '    <p class="day">'+d.eventDate_day+'</p>',
      string +=  '    <p class=day-nt>st</p>',
      string +=  '    <p class="month">'+d.eventDate_month+'</p>',
      string +=  '    <p class="year">'+d.eventDate_year+'</p>',
      string +=  '    </div>',
      string +=  '    </div>',
      string +=  '    </article>';
    }


    $(".hp-grid-wrapper").append($(string)).masonry({
      columnWidth: 'article',
      itemSelector:'article',
      percentPosition: true
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what to do. Hope it helps anyone else that had the same issue

```
            $(".hp-grid-wrapper").masonry({
          columnWidth: 'article',
          itemSelector:'article',
          percentPosition: true
        });
    var elems=$();
    var string ='';
    /// makes article tile
    for (var i = 0; i < newData.data.length;  i++) {
      var d = newData.data[i];

        string +=  '    <article class="'+d.type+'">',
        string +=  '    <div class="img-wrap">',
        string +=  '    <div class="grad"></div>',
        string +=  '    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/cats/" alt="" />',
        string +=  '    <h3 class="img-header"> This is a title</h3>',
        string +=  '    </div>',
        string +=  '    <div class="content-wrap">',
        string +=  '    <div class="publish-date">',
        string +=  '    <p>october</p>',
        string +=  '    <p>2015</p>',
        string +=  '    </div>',
        string +=  '    <div class="content-title">',
        string +=  '    <h3>'+d.title+'<h3>',
        string +=  '    </div>',
        string +=  '    <div class="summary">',
        string +=  '    <p>'+d.subtitle+'</p>',
        string +=  '    </div>',
        string +=  '    <div class="event-date">',
        string +=  '    <div class="event-date-month">',
        string +=  '    <p class="day">'+d.eventDate_day+'</p>',
        string +=  '    <p class=day-nt>st</p>',
        string +=  '    <p class="month">'+d.eventDate_month+'</p>',
        string +=  '    <p class="year">'+d.eventDate_year+'</p>',
        string +=  '    </div>',
        string +=  '    </div>',
        string +=  '    </article>';

        var elem = $(string);
        elems = elems ? elems.add( elem ) : elem;
        string ='';

      }
      $(".hp-grid-wrapper").append( elems );
      $(".hp-grid-wrapper").masonry('appended', elems);
      $(".hp-grid-wrapper").masonry();
};
```